When a creature enchanted with Fungal Fortitude dies and returns to the battlefield, does it keep Fungal Fortitude?
Fungal Fortitude is an Enchantment - Aura , which says "When enchanted creature dies, return it to the battlefield tapped under its owner's control."
So when a creature enchanted by Fungal Fortitude dies, does the creature retain the enchantments it had before dying?
In addition, does this return trigger any abilities with "When ___ enters the battlefield..."?

No, when a creature leaves the battlefield, auras attached to it will fall off and die. The creature that returns, even if it's the same card, is a new object with no relation to its former existence.
When a creature dies or otherwise leaves the battlefield, auras attached to it will die:

704.5m If an Aura is attached to an illegal object or player, or is not attached to an object or player, that Aura is put into its owner’s graveyard.

The creature that returns is a new object that has nothing to do with its previous existence. The aura that died was never attached to that new creature.

400.7. An object that moves from one zone to another becomes a new object with no memory of, or relation to, its previous existence. [..]



So when a creature enchanted by Fungal Fortitude dies, does the creature retain the enchantments it had before dying?

No. When a permanent leaves the battlefield, all other permanents that are attached to it are sent to the graveyard as a state-based action, unless there is something else that interferes with that (for instance, equipment has the special rule that when the permanent that it is attached to leaves the battlefield, it stays on the battlefield not attached to anything). Once the first permanent returns to the battlefield, the second permanent (in this case, Fungal Fortitude) is no longer on the battlefield to be attached to the first permanent, and the permanent is another object anyway, so the second permanent previously being attached has no effect.
Two mana would be much too cheap a cost if Fungal Fortitude returned to the battlefield. Compare with Gift of Immortality, which does return itself, but  costs three mana, doesn't give +2/+0, doesn't have Flash, and waits until the end step to come back (Flash is extremely valuable, since you can wait until your opponent targets your creature with removal or blocks it, and then cast Fungal Fortitude is response and have it attach before your opponent's spell resolves or the blocking creature deals damage).

In addition, does this return trigger any abilities with "When ___ enters the battlefield..."?

Yes. This triggers regardless of how the permanent entered the battlefield or whether it's been on the battlefield before (and since it's a new object, it wouldn't be considered to have been on the battlefield before anyway). Flicker effects also trigger ETB.
